# Let $A$ a Markov matrix and $x\in H_c$. Show that $e^{tA}H_c\subset H_c$ for all $t\in\Bbb R$

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

This is the exercise 17 in page 147 of *Analysis II* of Amann and Escher

> Suppose $A=[a^j_k]\in\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ is a Markov matrix, that is, it has $a^j_k\ge 0$ for all $j\neq k$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n a^j_k=1$ for $j=1,2,\ldots,n$. Also suppose $$H_c:=\left\{(x^1,\ldots,x^n)\in\Bbb R^n:\sum_{j=1}^n x^j=c\right\}\quad \text{ for }c\in\Bbb R$$
>
> Show that every solution of $\dot x=Ax$ with initial values in $H_c$ remains in $H_c$ for all time, that is, $e^{tA}H_c\subset H_c$ for $t\in\Bbb R$.

Something seems wrong in this exercise, maybe a typo or so. Observe that from the previous definition of Markov matrix we have that the identity matrix is a Markov matrix. However

$$e^{tI}=e^tI\,\text{ and }\,\mathbf z:= eI \mathbf x,\text{for } \mathbf x\in H_1\implies \sum_{j=1}^nz^j=e\sum_{j=1}^n x^j=e\implies\mathbf z\notin H_1$$

Im correct or there is something that Im overlooking?

P.S.: however I can see that for any Markov matrix $A$ as described above it holds that if $\mathbf x\in H_c$ then $A^n\mathbf x\in H_c$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.