# Show that if $f$ is totally differentiable at $x_0$ then some partial derivatives of $f$ exists in a neighborhood of $x_0$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, frechet-derivative

This is the exercise 6 in page 165 of *Analysis II* of Amann and Escher

> Suppose $X$ is open in $\Bbb R^n$, $F$ is a Banach space and $f:X\to F$. Also suppose that $x_0\in X$ and choose $\epsilon>0$ such that $\Bbb B(x_0,\epsilon)\subset X$. Finally let $$x_k(h):=x_0+h_1e_1+\ldots+h_ke_k\quad\text{for }k=1,2,\ldots,n\text{ and }h\in\Bbb B(x_0,\epsilon)$$
>
> Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ if and only if for every $h\in\Bbb B(x_0,\epsilon)$ such that $h_k\neq 0$ the limits $$\lim_{\substack{h_k\to 0\\h_k\neq 0}}\frac{f(x_k(h))-f(x_{k-1}(h))}{h_k},\quad k=1,\ldots,n$$ exists in $F$.

First some observations: the vectors $e_k$ are the standard basis of $\Bbb R^n$ and $h:=(h_1,\ldots,h_n)$. It seems a error the definition of $h\in\Bbb B(x_0,\epsilon)$ because its possible that $x_k(h)\notin X$. It seems that it must be $h\in\Bbb B(0,\epsilon)$ instead.

From now, to short things a little bit, I set $x_k:=x_k(h)$. I dont know exactly what to do or what to search for. Searching something for the first implication I search for an useful upper bound to show the existence of the total derivative at $x_0$, by example

$$\frac{\|f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)-\partial f(x_0)h\|}{|h|}=|h|^{-1}\left\|\left(\sum_{k=1}^n(f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1}))\right)-\partial f(x_0)\right\|\\\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\|f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})-\partial_k f(x_0)h_k\|}{|h_k|}$$

with $|h_k|\neq 0$ for all $k=1,\ldots,n$, and we used the fact that $|h|\ge|h_k|$. But I dont see how to continue from here.

After I thought that if I stablish an equivalence between the existence of the stated limits and the continuity of the partial derivatives of $f$ at $x_0$ Im done. But nothing useful comes from this idea.

Some help will be appreciated.

P.S.: I forget to say that the stated limits are equivalent to state the existence of the partial derivatives $\partial_k f(x_{k-1})$.

Comment: I do not understand what these limits are in "Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ if and only if for every $h\in\Bbb B(x_0,\epsilon)$ such that $h_k\neq 0$ the limits $$\lim_{\substack{h_k\to 0\\h_k\neq 0}}\frac{f(x_k(h))-f(x_{k-1}(h))}{h_k},\quad k=1,\ldots,n$$ exists in $F$."

Comment: @zhw these limits are by definition $\partial_k f(x_{k-1})$

Comment: Are you sure the limit is for $h_k \to 0$ and not for $h \to 0$ (under the constraint that $h_k \neq 0$)? As written, let $g$ the characteristic function of $\mathbb{Q}^n$ and $f(x) = \lVert x\rVert^2\cdot g(x)$. $f$ is differentiable at $0$, but partial derivatives exist only at some points. Take a more complicated $g$ and partial derivatives exist only at $0$.

Comment: @Daniel yes, I copied exactly, word by word and $\LaTeX$ by $\LaTeX$. I must add that probably the exercise is wrong, not sure anyway.

Comment: @Masacroso That's the wrong definition of partial derivatives. I don't know what they are.

Comment: @zhw I dont see why they are wrong... they follow exactly the definition of partial derivatives for the points $x_{k-1}$, that is, they are directional derivatives in the directions of the vector basis.

Comment: @Masacroso Hi! Recently, I've been working through Amann & Escher and so I'm having the same problem with these exercises as you did when you posted this question. Another wrong exercise is:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2409473/let-a-a-markov-matrix-and-x-in-h-c-show-that-etah-c-subset-h-c-for-all. I've just checked the original German version of this book (second, corrected edition), and it turns out that there's no problem with the translation. So why does it have such many mistakes (even in the corrected edition)? And what did you do about these? Thanks for any help!

Comment: @Masacroso BTW I think the "if" part of this exercise is true. Could it be a typo? (Though the German version says "genau dann", which means "if and only if")

Comment: @Colescu it is a first version. The entire book (I already read it and did all exercises) have some mistakes, not so much but some ones. The third book also have annoying mistakes (some one very bad ones) but fortunately they are a few. I think this is because the books are first versions, so they are not corrected. What is worse is that there is no an actualized errata of the books.

Comment: @Masacroso Thanks for the information! But shouldn't it be the second edition? The English version has a "Foreword to second edition" in the preface. I also have the German version, and it's "Zweite, korrigierte Auflage" (second, corrected edition), but even in this version the mistakes still exist. Anyway, it's a pity that such a renowned classic analysis text as this book is still filled with errors...

Comment: @Colescu you are right, it is a translation of a second edition. Yes, its a pity but still the books are very fine. You only need to take care of possible errors in exercises (probably there is some one in theory but I dont see it).